# Efficient way to trace performance

Tags: c#, performance

I have an asp.net (c#) project on a remote machine (I can log into this machine).

I want to trace its time consumption (mainly bll code).

Now I use logger with time Stamps, but I thought maybe someone has an better tool\way.

Thanks for any idea

Comment: have you enabled Tracing and look at the Trace Viewer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We do this 24x7 in production here at stackoverflow using mvc-mini-profiler, which we have released as open-source (just search). With it, I can tell you instantly what TSQL was executed, as well as all the steps used in building this very page (with timing etc), including AJAX requests. And all for free, and with virtually zero impact.

(obviously you can limit the profile display to specific user accounts, etc)

Comment: @Elad this is a web-server; almost all machines are remote. I am on a different continent to my servers, and it works great.

Answer (score 0):

Logging is a great way of doing it.  You might try a profiler as well, sometimes they give you information you missed.  Jetbrains has one RedGate has one, there are others as well, some have free trial you could try it out.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into [mvc-mini-profilier](http://code.google.com/p/mvc-mini-profiler/) if you are using .Net 4.0 or greater.  It may need to store to a sql server.  It has a quick web ui but I normally ignore it and just use sql queries to get the data I need.